# Shared Element in Marshmallow and Oreo have different result

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I want to make a Activity of browsing pictures which likes the WeChat in Chatting Activity by shared element.
  But I found that. Using the same code , the animation is very smooth in the my first phone(Android 6.0). And in the second phone(Android 8.0), the animation has a little unsmooth.
  Have you ever encountered such a situation? Do you know the reason? Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found in my demo, if your activity is as follows

```
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.changebounds_with_test))
```

And your transition is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500">
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <changeClipBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

The point is the duration which is greater than 300ms(default duration). Then the animation of Shared Element is unsmooth in Oreo.
But I had not set SharedElementEnterTransition in my project, the animation is also unsmooth in Oreo.
I think my project has any logic of code that influence the animation, which leads to the duration greater than 300ms.
Now I don't use shared element, and use value animation to make transition animation.